# Python: get an .exe file, and setting its icon

Tags: python, icons, exe

I'm looking for a function that gets an .exe file's path, gets his icon, changes it, and setting his icon to the new icon.
It will be something like this:

```
def set_icon(exe_path):
    ico = get(exe_path)
    ico = change(ico)
    set(exe_path, ico)
```

I realy don't know how to do the get and set functions.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you need a platform independent solution or Windows specific?

Comment: Platform independent solution would be the best, but Windows specific will be great too.